# An idiom or proverb for very easy to find but you are unable to see the object, which is very beside or close to you

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request, proverbs

For example:

> A speaker said to a listener go in and bring me the chair. He went in and looked for it but couldn't find, then the speaker said, " Where were you looking for the chair? It is beside you bring it here!

I'm also looking for  a single word for a person who is unable to find

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

> It is right there. If it was a snake it would have bit you.

or something similar, in the form of:

> If it was (something obvious) it would have (done something bad to you).

The point being you should be more aware of your surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

I think the expression you may be looking for is "can't see for looking".

Comment: Yes It's very close to that do you have another idiom

Answer (score 1):

The phrase I've most often heard is:

> It's right under your nose!

This phrase stems from one's inability to see what is directly under their own nose, despite it being very close to them. The listener might say:

> "I finally found the chair! It was right under my nose the whole time!"

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like "**to be blind as a bat**" (*surrounding's awareness, as user3169 told you* and also @smatterer "if you do not see it, you do not see it" - to explain the sense of touch).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a single word that describes what you seem to be thinking of. User3169 suggested "if it was a snake, it would have bit you," which is a folk saying that means to fail to find something very close to you. That saying does not imply, however, that you fail to find it because you are too close to it. The proverb implying that you fail to perceive because you are too close is "can't see the forest for the trees." That proverb, however, is primarily about mental perception, not about finding physical objects.

Answer (score 0):

A similar phrase would be:

> It's right in front of you!

Also, to respond to your second request, the adjective **blind** can be used in this context. It is used as a figure of speech. So in combination with the first phrase, you would say to someone,

> Are you blind? It's right in front of you!